# Apple Music downloaded songs when Cancel subscription and never connect to internet again

Tags: apple-music

What happens when you subscribe to Apple Music and download songs to a device and then permanently disconnect the from the internet and then use a different device (say pc) to cancel your subscription?

Do you keep your downloads in the first device until you connect to the internet again? How does Apple "tell the device" that the membership is no longer in place if you never connect to the internet again?